# Mocking Services in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I'm working on an AngularJS project. My project will hit a REST API that will be available at `http://www.myserver.com/customers`. That API has not been built yet. From my understanding, I can fake the response so that I can continue developing. However, I do not understand how to do that. Currently, I have the following code:

**index.js**

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, customerService) {
  ...
  $scope.getCustomers = function() {
    customerService.getCustomers.then(
      function(res) {
        console.log('customers retrieved from server!');
        console.log(res);
      },
      function() {
        console.log('there was an error.');
      }
   );
  };
  ...
});
```

**customerService.js**

```
myApp.service('customerService', function($http, $q) {
  this.getCustomers = function() {
    return $http.get('http://www.myserver.com/customers');
  };
});
```

How do I mock the results of the REST API call?

Thank you!

Comment: angular has a mock service and something with $httpBackendService. I have not been able to figure it out though and I just use placeholder objects in my controllers. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/object/angular.mock

Comment: Are you attempting to mock the service (to test the controller) or mock the $http call (to test the service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a promise resolved with the sample data...

```
myApp.service('customerService', function($http, $q) {
  this.getCustomers = function() {
    var data = [{id: 1, value: 'foo'}, {id: 2, value: 'bar'}];
    return $q.when(data);
  };
});
```

Then when the backend is ready, you can change the service to use `$http`, unwrap the response and return the data from the service (you'll probably want to add error handling too). There should be no need to change to the code that calls the service...

```
myApp.service('customerService', function($http, $q) {
  this.getCustomers = function() {
    return $http.get('http://www.myserver.com/customers')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };
});
```